# Blackberry Eclipse plugin and Eclipse Helios

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I am installing a new setup on my laptop, so I have installed Helios version of Eclipse.  I downloaded the Blackberry Plugin for Eclipse and during install, when prompted for the path to Eclipse, it stated that 3.6.x is not compatible, press CONTINUE to upgrade to 3.5.x [sic].

I chose to continue, but I am concerned.  Will it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is working correctly, I'm using Helios since June with the plugin, and there are no problems with. Everything is working fine.

Comment: @Michael B. I installed the plugin on Helios, via http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java. Smooth installation but no BlackBerry menus in Preferences. Can help?

Comment: @Giorgio Vespucci, check the about eclipse, to make sure the plugin installed correctly

Comment: @Michael B. Plugin `net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack5.0.0 (5.0.0.25) "BlackBerry Java SDK version 5.0.0"` installed. I have previously installed the full JDE for trying it (another folder!). Maybe this causes problems?

Comment: @Giorgio Vespucci, the JDE is a full IDE, it shouldn't interfere with eclipse at all. Can you create a new BlackBerry project ?

Comment: @Michael B. Thanks for you attention :) Strictly speaking I'm not able to create it, because there is no BlackBerry folder under "New project" dialog. Damn'it, damn'it, damn'it... OK, I will post a real question about it. I will send you the link. Thank you